# XSLT code - Create a new XML segment for every 3 xml segments

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I'm still learning and enhancing my XSLT skills. But hope it's okay if i can see from experts regarding my requirement.

For every 3 records xml segment, a new record xml segment will be created position on top which will sum the amount of the 3 records. Then, a new record (PK50) segment will still be produced in excess or the remaining line items. Kindly see the sample data below. There are PK50 records created, where the last one contains the summation of the remaining 2 records.

PostingKey 50 indicates the new record created which contains the amount summation of every 3 records. The Account field will have a value "Summation" as well. Appreciate any inputs from your end. Thank you so much!

Source data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:AccrualReport xmlns:ns1="http://client.com/expense/expensereport">
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>lines</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>12.5</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>12.5</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>lines</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>22</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>22</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>1.15</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>1.15</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>20</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>20</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>1</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>1</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>2</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>2</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>1</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>1</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>1</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>1</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
</ns1:AccrualReport>
```

Output Expected data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:AccrualReport xmlns:ns1="http://client.com/expense/expensereport">
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>50</PostingKey>
        <Account>Summation</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>35.65</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>35.65</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>lines</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>12.5</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>12.5</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>lines</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>22</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>22</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>1.15</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>1.15</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>50</PostingKey>
        <Account>Summation</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>23</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>23</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>20</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>20</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>1</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>1</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>2</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>2</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>50</PostingKey>
        <Account>Summation</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>2</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>2</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>1</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>1</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <CoCode>BI10</CoCode>
        <DocDate>25/01/2022</DocDate>
        <PostDate>25/01/2022</PostDate>
        <DocType>SB</DocType>
        <PostingKey>40</PostingKey>
        <Account>60875000</Account>
        <Amt_DocCurr>1</Amt_DocCurr>
        <Amt_LocCurr>1</Amt_LocCurr>
    </Record>
</ns1:AccrualReport>
```

So far, here's the current code which I am using. The only problem is the summation of the amount in the Amt_DocCurr and Amt_LocCurr. Appreciate any inputs to handle this and incorporate in my current code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="rows" select="3"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[position() mod $rows = 1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <Record>
            <CoCode><xsl:value-of select="CoCode"/></CoCode>
            <DocDate><xsl:value-of select="DocDate"/></DocDate>
            <PostDate><xsl:value-of select="PostDate"/></PostDate>
            <DocType><xsl:value-of select="DocType"/></DocType>
            <PostingKey>50</PostingKey>
            <Account>Summation</Account>
            <Amt_DocCurr><xsl:value-of select="Amt_DocCurr"/></Amt_DocCurr>
            <Amt_LocCurr><xsl:value-of select="Amt_LocCurr"/></Amt_LocCurr> 
        </Record>
        <xsl:copy-of select=".|following-sibling::Record[not(position() > $rows -1)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns1:AccrualReport xmlns:ns1="http://client.com/expense/expensereport">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ns1:AccrualReport>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Seems a positional grouping problem, start with the introductionsamples in [tag:xslt-grouping]: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way this could be done :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <AccrualReportOutput>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="AccrualReport/Record[position() mod 2 = 0]"/>
    </AccrualReportOutput>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:variable name="group" select=". | preceding-sibling::Record[1]"/>
    <!-- Create new Summation Record -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="* except (Account, PostingKey, Amt_DocCurr, Amt_LocCurr)"/>
      <Account>Summation</Account>
      <PostingKey>50</PostingKey>
      <Amt_DocCurr><xsl:value-of select="sum($group/Amt_DocCurr)"/></Amt_DocCurr>
      <Amt_LocCurr><xsl:value-of select="sum($group/Amt_LocCurr)"/></Amt_LocCurr>
    </xsl:copy>
    <!-- Copy 2 Records of group -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="$group"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aB9NKz/1

(I have removed your ns1: namespace prefix, not knowing what that namespace is, being undeclared in your XML.)

Comment: Hi Sebastien, thank you very much for your feedback. There's a change in the requirement, where for every 3 records xml segment, a new record xml segment will be created position on top which will sum the amount of the 3 records. Then, a new record (PK50) segment will still be produced in excess or the remaining line items. Kindly see the updated sample data above. There are three (3) PK50 records created, where the last one contains the summation of the remaining 2 records. I've also updated the namespace. Kindly advise for the changes of the XSLT code. I can't seem to make it work :(

Comment: @Fred you need to do an effort on your part. You haven't posted any of the code you have written. Merely saying it does not work does not help much.

Comment: Hi Sebastien, i've updated the post with the current code I am trying to work. Your code is actually helpful and working grouping and summing every 2 records. But when i've made the source data not in even count (e.g., total records = 7), the output is only populating 3 PK50 summation records. Since, there's an excess of 1 record, there's still another PK50 record to be produced which will contain the summation of the excess record. The code which i've updated in this blog can handle the creation of the PK50 based from the defined number of record to be grouped, but the summation is missing :(